# Public Wi-Fi with Individual Authentication and Time limit for Internet Access

Tags: authentication, wifi, local-area-network, access-point

I would like to change the way that my costumers access to the internet. I would like to enable **two ways for sharing my internet**:

1. With my **wireless network as public**, I would like to give a
   **username and password** to a user, this way he can access to the
   Internet for a **limited time (determined by him)**. Just users with a
   username, password and "credit" can access to the internet. The
   **authentication must be over a web page**.
2. As #1, with public wireless network, I would to share **temporary
   codes** (generated by a my server) that allows users to access
   internet in their devices for a **limited time (determined by the
   server)**. Authentication must be over web, and all users need to have 
   a specific temporary "**ticket**" (that loses its capability to
   provide internet after it was used).

*It is important to say, that each user need to have a time control. When it expires, the user needs to be redirected to the Auth page.*

**I know that it is possible**, I just want some **specific names** for this approach, may be some **tools**, **tutorials**, **guides**...

*Anybody can help me?* **:)**

THANKS A LOT

Comment: Why? Why downvoting?

Comment: Because your question is [off topic for ServerFault](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6139/when-is-a-request-for-product-recommendations-not-a-request-for-product-recommen/6140#6140), would be my guess.

Comment: I didn't dv, but it's likely because you showed no evidence of research or attempted solutions.

Comment: Sorry guys, I didn't know how to start my research because I am not in domain to know to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is essentially a "Captive Portal" server for your wireless networks.

I would suggest you look at [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/), it is an open source Firewall/Unified Threat Management system and has [Captive Portal](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Captive_Portal) functionality built in.

You can also do time restrictions based on VLAN, IP, MAC, Route, etc. Very powerful platform. Even lets you produce vouchers